React Native Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'
I am developing an app for Android. I use React Native with Expo. I build my application with the eas build command and then choose Android on the terminal.
Unfortunately the build fails. You can see the logs below:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 5m 3s 320 actionable tasks: 320 executed Error: Gradle build failed with unknown
error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.


I will be glad if someone knows how to fix this issue.
